# mysql Inner join with different table

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

thanks all of you :) i have 4 table Project, points, steps, and comments;

**Project** 
id
name
desc

**points**
id
name
desc
project_id

**steps**
id
desc
points_id

**comments**
id
desc
steps_id

i wrote query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Project 
INNER JOIN points ON points.project_id=Project.id
INNER JOIN steps ON steps.points_id=points.id
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.steps_id=steps.id
WHERE Project.id=333
```

one project has many points, points, has many steps, and it has many comments 
somthing like this, and i whant to get all results in one query otherwise it takes a lot of time get results :(( i have no idea what can i do to :((

it is like this

```
**Project**
id :1,
name :"get",

**points**
id :1,
name :"points1", ///project "get"'s point
project_id : 1,
id :2,
name :"points2", ///project "get"'s point
project_id : 1,

**steps**
id :1,
name :"steps1", ///project "points2"'s step
points_id : 2,
id :2,
name :"steps2",///project "points2"'s step
points_id : 2,

**comments**
id :1,
name :"something", ///project "steps1"'s comment
steps_id : 1,
id :2,
name :"something",///project "steps2"'s comment
steps_id : 2,
```

i want to echo project, it's point, point's step and step's comments in one query or if there are another way to solve this problem?  thanks for supporting :))))))

Comment: try left joins instead of inner joins. and sort the table join order by containment.

Comment: you need to add more details. The joined columns depend on your condition.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always provide the problem that you are facing. Here you are saying you have this and that and you are doing this. But still I am not getting what I want. HOW would we know what you want? Please let us know what you are expecting by providing desired input.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have an invalid sql syntax. You missed the keyword `FROM`. It should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
       INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id= table1.id
       INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.table2_id= table2.id
       INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.table3_id= table3.id
WHERE table1.ID = 333
```

But I need your desired result. You need to specify your database schema and dummy records to complete your query.

Answer (score 1):

Few thing missing in your posted query:

1. Missing `FROM` clause
2. Also, every join is not correct like `table2.table1_id= table1.id` ... it should be
   `table2.table2_id= table1.id` (Unless your table design is like so)

So, ultimately your query should look like

```
SELECT *  FROM Table1        
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.table2_id= table1.id        
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.table2_id= table1.id        
INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.table4_id= table1.id 
WHERE table1.ID = 333
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently retrieving all columns from Table1 by filtering the ID with value 333. What about further columns from other tables? what kind of resut you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the last INNER JOIN. table2 should be table4.